# How can I add property to custom workflow activity that allows selection of another entity from workflow?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm working a custom workflow activity and would like to allow the user to select one of the entities available from within the workflow. This would be like selecting the entity in an update status activity. The list would include the primary entity, all of its associated parent entities, and any entities created within the workflow (e.g. if I created a task with the create activity, that task would be in the list).

Is there some way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflow has major shortcomings when it comes to things like this.  You can add metadata to dependencies ( [CrmInput] and [CrmReferenceTarget("account")] ), but you'll need a property per entity you intend to support.  I don't know if you could include multiple CrmReferenceTarget tags per property.

So even if you go through setting up a workflow activity with every lookup (which will require a code change for every new entity), you still have to take the care to set the right lookup in your code - and choose from ALL (not filtered based on your entity).  Which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: NOT what I wanted to hear.  :,(  Thanks for the answer though. At least now I can try to think of other solutions/workarounds.